# Multiple Targets in Xcode can't find Cocapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I want to create multiple targets in my project so I duplicate my main target and add suffix "Dev". After have two target, I run "pod install" again in terminal but still get bellow error;

> unknown>:0: error: no such file or directory: 'COCOAPODS'
>   Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

My podlike:

```
def pods
# Pods for Garanti Filo
pod 'Alamofire'
end

target 'Hello' do
  use_frameworks!
    pods
 end
target 'Hello Dev' do
    use_frameworks!
    pods
end
```

In General tab of Main Target in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" part I have Pods_Hello.framework and In Dev target I have both Pods_Hello.framework and Pods_Hello_Dev.framework but dev frameworks icon is in light color

EDIT: I have changed "Other Swift Flags" inside Build Settings to "DDEVELOPMENT" from "D" and I found that problem was that. However, I still don't know how can I make it "DDEVELOPMENT" and make pods work for that.

Comment: can you tell me if my answer help you in some way?

Comment: No unfortunatelly...

Comment: Still the same error?

Comment: I solve it by deleting Cocoapods in swift other flags but I don't know It will cause any problem later

Comment: ok I will remove my answer then